# Orthogonalizing a Gaussian Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I'd like to know if does there exist real, continuous and differentiable functions $\omega(x)$ such that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2} +~ i\omega(x)}dx = 0$$

and what kind of tools one could use to prove their existence and construct them, if possible.

The reason behind this is that I'm trying to take a set of real functions $g_n$ of the type $$g_n(x) = e^{-\frac{(x + nL)^2}{2}}, x, L \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

and transform them into complex functions

$$g_n'(x) = g_n(x)e^{i\omega_n(x)}$$

with $\omega_n(x)$ real and such that

$$ A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_n'(x)\overline{g_m'(x)}dx = \delta_{nm}$$

where $A$ is a normalization constant. In Physics, this set of functions, if it exists, would define a discrete orthogonal basis, which can be used to derive the eigenstates and eigenenergies of periodic potentials, such as a crystal. Hence the title.

The closest I got to a solution was finding out that if we define $\omega(x) = \nu x,~\nu \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have that, according to Wolfram Alpha website,

$$ A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_n'(x)\overline{g_m'(x)}dx = A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x +nL)^2 + (x+mL)^2}{2}} e^{i(n-m)\nu x}dx = A'e^{-\frac{(n-m)^2\nu^2}{2}}, for ~n\neq m,$$
that is, we can get as small as we want, but never get to zero. I know this just because of the computational tool and I'm curious about how one would prove this last equation.

P.S.: Since I don't come from a mathematical background I'm not even sure how to tag this. Does this belong to functional analysis? Or integral equations, perhaps?

Comment: The function $$\omega(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & x\ge 0, \\ \pi, & x<0,\end{cases}$$ solves the problem but it is not continuous. Maybe you can try smoothing it symmetrically. The idea is to exploit the symmetry of the Gaussian with respect to $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: I have thought a little bit more and now I see that my previous comment leads nowhere. To exploit that symmetry, one should be able to find a function $\omega$ such that $\omega(-x)=\omega(x)+\pi$, but such a function cannot be continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Yep, I've reached the same conclusion, but perhaps that is a good start. Maybe we could first smooth it out around $x=0$, then calculate how much that makes the integral diverge from its wanted value (either 0 or 1). Then we could twist the edges (large $x$) a little in order to compensate this divergence. Does this make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, but I don't know if it will be easy, probably not. It is easy to make the integral as small as we want, but **exactly** 0 is difficult.